# How to insert multiple data in db that is append with ajax call in php and jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using ajax call to get employees for particular  company with `company_dropdown`. I am appending this data with table format in ajax call.

below is my ajax call it shows me proper data:

```
   $.each(data, function( index, value ) 
            {
                $(".bodytable").append( <tr>
                     <td style="width:250px;"><input type="text" name="emp_type" class="" value="'+value.typeOfEmployee+'">
                     </td>
                    <td style="width:250px;"><input type="text" name="emp_name" class="" value="'+value.comemp+'"><input type="hidden" name="emp_id" class="" value="'+value.empid+'">
                     </td>
                    <td><div><input type="file" name="payeslip[]" multiple><input type="hidden" name="emp_id" class="" value="'+value.empid+'">
                    </td>\
                   </tr>');
            });
```

As you can see my code i am getting `emp_type`,`emp_name`,`emp_id` with ajax call.

Suppose user will select one company `xyz` from dropdown and he will get all employees of particular company.

```
  id          employee_name        unique_id   emp_type
   1           Noah                    ABCD     internal
   2           Liam                    ABCD     internal
   3           William                 ABCD     internal
   4           Benjamin                ABCD     external
```

> Now, user can view above data with employee name, and employee type in
>   table format with one input type file to upload particular employee's
>   payslip.
>
> Now, if user will upload payslips for first 2 employee only then it
>   should be insert in table with 2 different rows. I have one function
>   to get multiple payslips with that i am able to insert multiple
>   payslips in different rows.

```
$com_name = $_POST['com_name'];
$payslips=$obj->payslips($_FILES['payeslip'],$com_name);
$form_data = array(
        'emp_id' => $_POST['emp_id'],
        'emp_type' => $_POST['emp_type']
    ); 
    $payslips= array($payslips);  
    $query1  = $obj->insert_payslip_data($form_data,$payslips,$com_name);



        function payslips($files,$com_name)
            {
                   $payslips="";
                    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['payeslip']['name']); $i++) 
                    {
                       $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['payeslip']['tmp_name'][$i];    
                       if ($tmpFilePath != "")
                        {    
                            if (!file_exists('../pay_slips/'.$com_name)) 
                                {
                                    mkdir('../pay_slips/'.$com_name, 0777, true);
                                }
                            $location = '../pay_slips/'.$com_name.'/';
                           $name = $_FILES['payeslip']['name'][$i];
                           $size = $_FILES['payeslip']['size'][$i];

                           list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);

                           //$file= rand().time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 0);
                           $file = substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 0);
                           $info = pathinfo($file);
                           $filename = $file.".".$ext;
                           if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['payeslip']['tmp_name'][$i], $location.$filename)) 
                           { 
                              $payslips.=$filename.",";
                           }
                        }
                    }


                $payslip = rtrim($payslips, ',');
                return $payslip;
            }
```

And then i have insert function :

```
 public function insert_payslip_data($form_data,$payslips,$com_name)
    {

        $con = $this->__construct();
        $data = explode(',', $payslips[0]);
        $items = array();
        foreach ($data as $value) 
            {

                $sql = "INSERT INTO `pay_slips`(`com_id`, `payslip`, `created_date`, 
                `created_by`,`emp_id`,`emp_type`) VALUES ('".$id."', '".$com_name."','".$value."',NOW(),'".$_SESSION['email']."','".$form_data['emp_id']."','".$form_data['emp_type']."')";
                $execute = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            }
        return $execute;
    }
```

By above all code i am able to upload files into database with different rows.
But problem is every time in `emp_id` and `emp_type` columns it goes with last row from my data.

If i upload first 2 employees payslips into database then in database it storing like :

```
   id             pay_slip            emp_id   emp_type
   1           Noah_payslip.pdf        4       external
   2           Liam_payslip.pdf        4       external
```

Expected Output:

```
  id             pay_slip            emp_id    emp_type
   1           Noah_payslip.pdf        1       internal
   2           Liam_payslip.pdf        2       internal
```

Comment: Because you have same name for all your input element which are appending in table. You should have different name of those elements or should create an array.

Comment: @RohitMittal i dont have same names for input element. that is typo bro.

Comment: Here in your code: <td style="width:250px;"><input type="text" name="emp_type" class="" value="'+value.typeOfEmployee+'"></td>, check name is emp_type which shows you have same name. If it is not then please update your question

Comment: i dont understand in what condition your saying that same name.

Comment: in first snippet of this question. you are appending table row as $(".bodytable").append( <tr><td style="width:250px;"><input type="text" name="emp_type" class="" value="'+value.typeOfEmployee+'"></td><td style="width:250px;"><input type="text" name="emp_name" class="" value="'+value.comemp+'"><input type="hidden" name="emp_id" class="" value="'+value.empid+'"></td><td><div><input type="file" name="payeslip[]" multiple><input type="hidden" name="emp_id" class="" value="'+value.empid+'"></td>\</tr>'); Here you have same name as name="emp_type" and name="emp_name".

Comment: bro im using array for this but in array it shows me all emp_id and emp_type `Array ( [0] => customer_info_(24).pdf [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 5 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Employee [1] => Employee [2] => Shareholder ) )`  i want only those emp_id and emp_type whose payslip will be filled by user